# How to read filepath from app config without adding question mark?

Tags: c#, .net

When i try to read a file from app.config it add a question mark at the begining of the path it's why i receive an error after that

My App.Config code part

```
<add key="filePath" value="‪C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\0004_637117481488357800_02000.json" />
```

My class part

```
public static String JsonFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath"];

Console.WriteLine(JsonFilePath);

lFileName = Path.GetFileName(JsonFilePath);

if (File.Exists(JsonFilePath))
{
    Console.WriteLine(JsonFilePath);
}
```

It give me the filename without any problem, but it doesn't find the JsonFilePath because it become like that :

```
?C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\0004_637117481488357800_02000.json
```

How to have that same path without the question mark ? And why it's added automaticly ?

Comment: Doesn't make sense. My guess: you copied the path from somewhere and accidentally copied a control character. Open the file in Notepad++, show all non-printing characters and look for an inverted black/white control character like [RS] or something at  the beginning of your path.

Comment: I have another project with the same code, and it doesn't have that problem

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, there is no non-printing characters in path. @user2184260 Can you share the complete sample, e.g. the complete `app.config`? Is this key placed under the `appSettings`?

Comment: Is it a Web Service or a Web Method? You may get in services.

Comment: yes it's inside the appSettings under connectionStrings

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same issue. Before the first character of the string (inserted by copy/paste) there should be an invisible symbol (notepad++ does not show it). Remove it and reenter the string manually to resolve this issue.